# Identifying Parent transaction on set of records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of transactions and its payments. I am looking for finding the parent payment for the transactions to identify the repeated customers. For example, I have list as below:

```
   Transaction  Payment1    Payment2    Payment3    Bucket
       100         A           B          C             P1
       110         B                                    P1
       120         D           E                        P2
       130         D           E          F             P2
       140         C           B                        P1
       160         F           K                        P2
       170         C           A                        P1
```

Parent Transaction is the final result. It need not be A and D always, which ever is the best in finding the Unique value, for eg: Instead of A, it can B or C if we can derive it easily.

I tried going by iterations, first comparing column 3 with col1 and col2 values and deriving the Col1 of first finding as parent. But some where it is not working at all. I have more than million transactions to derive the parent payment to identify the unique customer.

Example is for transaction 100, I used 3 different payment cards (Like Visa, Master Card, AMEX, Debit card, Gift card). I might be using any of these cards in any other transactions. For example Payment B, I used B in Transaction 110. So 100 and 110 should be under same bucket. For transaction 140 and 170, I used payments C,B & C,A. All these cards are from the same person. SO all these transactions should come under same bucket. I want to identify that bucket. Let us name all these set of transactions as P1 and if I query on P1, I should get all these transactions. Same applies to other set of transactions.

Comment: how do you know the Transaction id of Payement 'A'?

Comment: Using Oracle DBMS, and the data is a table dervied from Sales transaction tables where I dont have access. This is the table I can access.

Comment: I don't understand what algorithm you are going through in your sample data to determine the "Parent Payment" value.  I don't understand how you know which transactions are related and what process you want to follow to find the "parent".

Comment: Given the data you have shown above, please explain how to determine that the parent payment of transaction 110 is A. Likewise, please explain how to determine that the parent payment of transaction 160 is D. Perhaps there is other data which is needed to make this determination? Thanks.

Comment: for 100, A,B,C falls under one bucket. Since 110 has B this will fall in same bucket, as 140 and 170. So I 100,110,140 and 170 falls under same bucket. So I have A as parent transaction. There is no logic behind it. Just an assumption based on first transaction and it can  B or C also.

Comment: For 120, 130, 160 it will fall under same bucket as D,E,F with K will define its transactions and these Payments has link. D, E under 120 and again D also happened for 130, so D,E,F will be under one bucket. For 160 we have F which is already under D,E,F which will add K payment under the same bucket.

Comment: My main point here based on transactions and its payments details, just for example I bought some electronics for 100$ and I used my credit card for 50$, debit card for 25$ and Gift card for remaining 25$. Some other day I made another transaction and I bought for 50$. I used the same credit card I used before for 25$ and remaining 25$ on Master card. Another transaction I used totally on my master card.I want to bring these 3 transactions under one buckets, which means I am trying to identify repeated customers to get their sales trend.

Comment: @BobJarvis : hope you got clarification. Do you have any solution

Comment: @JustinCave: Hope you got clarification, do you have any solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand.  First, please edit your question rather than posting additional detail in comments.  If A, B, and C are supposed to be the $50, $25, and $25 payments in your example, the idea that you can identify a "parent" transaction because the transaction amounts match seems very, very odd.  It sounds like you are asking to find the `Payment1` value for the row with the smallest `TransactionID` where the `Payment1`, `Payment2`, or `Payment3` value matches any of the `Payment1`, `Payment2`, or `Payment3` values in the current row.  Is that correct?

Comment: I agree with @JustinCave - I still don't understand what it is you're trying to do. Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and include sufficient explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks.. I figured out a solution, wrote a function in R, took the data in R and wrote a loop and did a logic of identifying parent transaction and put it back into database. Since it is millions of records, it is taking 2 days to execute but with accuracy.